# How can I pass URL variables in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, variables

I have created a custom page named 'photo' in Wordpress and using a permalink structure like "%category%/%postname%". Now I need to pass some URL variables like the following -

http://wordpress.local/photo/id/200/action/resize/width/300/height/260

The GET variable should look like the following array. How to do this without touching the .htaccess file?

array(
    'id' => 200,
    'action' => 'resize',
    'width' => 300,
    'height' => 260
);

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite), you could add your own rules using `add_filter()` with the `rewrite_rules_array` parameter.